# MySQL Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'prod_code' at row 7

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm using MySQL Workbench 5.7

I have the following table created and stored procedure:

```
DROP TABLE MV_SALESBYMONTH;
CREATE TABLE MV_SALESBYMONTH
(
`time_year` int, `time_month` int, `prod_code` int,`sale_units` int, `sale_price` int);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure `REFRESH_MV_SALESBYMONTH` () BEGIN 

    TRUNCATE TABLE `MV_SALESBYMONTH`;

    INSERT INTO MV_SALESBYMONTH 
    (SELECT TIME_YEAR AS 'YEAR', TIME_MONTH AS 'MONTH', PROD_CODE AS 'PRODUCT',
    SUM(SALE_UNITS) AS 'UNITS SOLD', SUM(SALE_UNITS*SALE_PRICE) AS 'SALES TOTAL'
    FROM TIME T, SALES S
    WHERE S.TIME_ID = T.TIME_ID
    GROUP BY TIME_YEAR, TIME_MONTH, PROD_CODE);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

STEP 5: Using the Materialized View

```
CALL REFRESH_MV_SALESBYMONTH();

SELECT * FROM MV_SALESBYMONTH;
```

When I try to run the statement:

```
CALL REFRESH_MV_SALESBYMONTH();
```

I get the error 1265: Data Truncated for column 'prod_code' at row 7

Comment: What's the data type of the column sales.prod_code?

Comment: Looking at the table: MV_SALESBYMONTH:    prod_code is an integer.                                                                                                   CREATE TABLE MV_SALESBYMONTH
(
`time_year` int, `time_month` int, `prod_code` int,`sale_units` int, `sale_price` int);

Comment: What type is `PROD_CODE` from `TIME T, SALES S`? (Using the table aliases makes the query more readable.)

Comment: I was given this SELECT statement from which I had to create the Procedure I posted above:                                                                                                                                                                                                                      SELECT TIME_YEAR AS "YEAR", TIME_MONTH AS "MONTH", PROD_CODE AS "PRODUCT",
SUM(SALE_UNITS) AS "UNITS SOLD", SUM(SALE_UNITS*SALE_PRICE) AS "SALES TOTAL"
FROM TIME T, SALES S
WHERE S.TIME_ID = T.TIME_ID
 GROUP BY TIME_YEAR, TIME_MONTH, PROD_CODE;

Comment: That select statement is looking at a table called sales. That's the origin of the data, where it comes from. Examine that table to check what the data types are. Why repeat information you already posted in the original question when we are asking for the missing information that's not there?

Comment: I was only given the following 3 outputs. So I don't have the construct for the Sales table.

Comment: MONTH PRODUCT    TOTAL SALES
---------- ---------- -----------
         9 13-Q2/P2        142.91
         9 1546-QQ2         623.9
         9 2232/QTY        109.92
         9 2238/QPD          77.9
         9 23109-HB          71.7
         9 54778-2T         47.92
         9 89-WRE-Q        258.95
         9 PVC23DRT         99.79
         9 SM-18277         26.85
         9 WR3/TT3         335.85
         9                1795.69

Comment: MONTH PRODUCT    TOTAL SALES
---------- ---------- -----------
        10 13-Q2/P2        111.93
        10 2232/QTY        109.92
        10 23109-HB          47.8
        10 54778-2T         23.96
        10 89-WRE-Q        258.95
        10 PVC23DRT         99.79
        10 SM-18277         26.85
        10 WR3/TT3         335.85
        10                1015.05
           13-Q2/P2        254.84
           1546-QQ2         623.9

Comment: MONTH PRODUCT    TOTAL SALES
---------- ---------- -----------
           2232/QTY        219.84
           2238/QPD          77.9
           23109-HB         119.5
           54778-2T         71.88
           89-WRE-Q         517.9
           PVC23DRT        199.58
           SM-18277          53.7
           WR3/TT3          671.7
                          2810.74

Comment: Cool.. truncated means cut off, like the value you want to put there doesn't fit.. in this case, your product code is probably a string of text.. but the prod_code you've got in mv_salesbymonth is an integer (whole number).. so can't fit.

Comment: You can probably see the sales table using DESCRIBE sales.. your query can definitely see that table in the database.. because it gets as far as reading the data and trying to insert it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-information.html

Comment: If you look at the sales table, you can see how many characters are possible in prod_code.. then you define prod_code in mv_salesbymonth so it can hold that many characters of text too.

Comment: Either that or product code is a big integer, so you would define prod_code as bigint in mv_salesbymonth

Comment: i got it -   I updated the create table statement to:    CREATE TABLE MV_SALESBYMONTH
(
`time_year` int, `time_month` int, `prod_code` varchar(100),`sale_units` int, `sale_price` int);

Comment: It worked I got to display the 18 rows and columns I needed, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define prod_code as varchar(100) in the create table statement. That way it can hold the maximum number of characters possible in the source data.